# Delegates in C# (un)explained example - looks same as method call would appear

Tags: c#, delegates

I finally understood how to use delegates, but can't really figure out why use them instead of method calls. I found this answer pasted bellow, but I can't figure out what is a big difference between those two, because I could simply say

```
double tot1 = CalcTotalMethod1(100.34);
double tot2 = CalcTotalMethod2(100.34);
```

instead of

```
double tot1 = CalcMyTotal(100.34, CalcTotalMethod1);
double tot2 = CalcMyTotal(100.34, CalcTotalMethod2);
```

This is a example:

```
public static double CalcTotalMethod1(double amt)
{
    return amt * .014;
}

public static double CalcTotalMethod2(double amt)
{
    return amt * .056 + 42.43;
}


public delegate double calcTotalDelegate(double amt);

public static double CalcMyTotal(double amt, calcTotalDelegate calcTotal)
{
    return calcTotal(amt);
}

double tot1 = CalcMyTotal(100.34, CalcTotalMethod1);
double tot2 = CalcMyTotal(100.34, CalcTotalMethod2);
Console.WriteLine(tot1);
Console.WriteLine(tot2);
```

Comment: Read [Real World Functional Programming: With Examples in F# and C#](http://www.amazon.com/Real-World-Functional-Programming-Examples/dp/1933988924). It's not an easy read, but it will Change The Way You Think. I can't explain in a few paragraphs what the authors take chapters to cover.

Comment: @TrueWill thanks for reminding me of that one; I proof-read a very early and incomplete draft, but I have never been back to read the finished book. Must do that.

Answer (score 4):

The difference is that you are telling `CalcMyTotal` which method to use - functional composition. `CalcMyTotal` doesn't know about either of the methods involved (or any other you could dream up) - and doesn't need to. All it needs to know is "you give me a way to do something, I'll do it". In a more typical example, `CalcMyTotal` would be doing something a bit more than just calling the method, for example:

```
var somethingTricky = LotsOfWork(amt);
var intermediateValue = calcTotal(somethingTricky);
return SomeMoreWork(intermediateValue);
```

The point here: the caller doesn't need to know what goes on inside `CalcMyTotal` - it just needs to supply some mechanism to "calc total"; and `CalcMyTotal` doesn't need to know anything about the mechanism involved. You could think of it as a single-method interface.

For completeness, you could also do that (perhaps more clearly) as:

```
public static double CalcMyTotal(double amt, Func<double,double> calcTotal) {...}
```

(note the `Func<...>` usage), and invoke with lambda syntax:

```
double tot1 = CalcMyTotal(100.34, amt => amt * 0.014);
```

Answer (score 4):

Its because you are dealing with trivial examples.....

Imagine if you are a designer of a library,  you want other people to pass different methods into CalcMyTotal.

or..... perhaps simpler,   when someone clicks a button on a user interface, you want to be able to plug different functions in to do different things when the button is clicked

Answer (score 3):

Some differences are:

- Delegates allow for [multicasting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173175%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) (i.e., more than one element of the delegate type in its invocation list).
- Delegates allow for some level of decoupling between the invoker and the specific function being invoked.
- The above allows delegates to be sent into functions that know nothing about the subscribers and the implementation. Then, you have an implementation of the publisher / subscribers pattern.
- Delegates are a stepping stone to creating Events, which use delegates for notification of 0-N subscribers of the fact that a particular event has occurred along with passing data describing the event details to all subscribers.

Comment: (multicasting was the only bullet item when I added this comment) well.... *yes*, but that isn't how it is being used in the example

Comment: It's not part of the example presented, but it certainly is within the confines of the original question.

Comment: not really; a delegate with a return value, if not specifically coded to deconstruct into individual calls, will only yield the last return value. Hence, the code **as presented in the question** (as a function) will not be useful for multicast.

Comment: @Marc, you're right of course, but let me reiterate the original question: I finally understood how to use delegates, but can't really figure out why use them instead of method calls. I found this answer pasted bellow, but I can't figure out what is a big difference between those two, because I could simply say. --- The sample code presented is just an example, not the jist of the question ---

Comment: OK guys, you're both making a good point. I stated the example only to ask what's the big difference, but any other example that will make programmer's life easier is welcomed.

Comment: From what I've seen so far, multicasting is a perfect reason to use them, but for those simple examples where there's only one function call, it just doesn't click yet :)

Answer (score 2):

Delegates are most useful when you need to pass a reference to a method around. Examples include [events in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739(v=vs.71).aspx) and [sorting with a custom comparator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z.aspx).

An example of the latter:

```
class Thing
{
    private int value;

    public static int CompareTwoThings(Thing one, Thing other)
    {
        if (one.value < other.value) return -1;
        if (one.value > other.value) return 1;
        return 0;
    }
}

// elsewhere
List<Thing> things = GetSomeThings();
things.Sort(Thing.CompareTwoThings);
```

Of course, in this case you really should have `Thing` implement `IComparable` instead, but this is just an example of how you can use a delegate as a custom sort function.

Comment: You didn't declare `CompareTwoThings` as delegate, why? It's a interesting example, but sorry for me being a newbie, how does `Sort` method know what to compare?

Comment: @HomeMade The compiler will create a delegate for `Thing.CompareTwoThings`; this is called "implicit method group conversion".  The delegate will take two parameters of type `Thing` and return an integer value (because that's the signature of `CompareTwoThings` and because there's an overload of `List<T>.Sort` that takes a `Comparison<T>` parameter).